# AngularJS make ng-repeat generic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to make one directive using ng-repeat, where I have two use cases.  In one use case, I want to print the object for each repeat (person).  In the other, I want to print a property of the person object for each repeat (ie. person.age). Here is an example:

```
Use case 1:
    <list-maker items="People" object="item"/>

Use case 2 
    <list-maker items="People" object="item.age"/>

Directive: listMaker
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{object}}
    </div>
```

Any reason why this won't work, or any ideas on a solution?  I would really prefer to use the same directive.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to embed an [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) inside your 'listMaker' directive.

For example:

```
Directive: listMaker
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div ng-switch="item.age">
            <div ng-switch-when="0">
                {{object}}
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default>
                {{object.age}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This will print the entire object when the instance's age property has a value of 0, and the age property otherwise.